Error in doctrine/doctrine-fixtures-bundle 3.7.0: Too few arguments to function Doctrine\Common\DataFixtures\AbstractFixture::getReference()
After composer update updated my doctrine/doctrine-fixtures-bundle to v3.7.0 and doctrine/data-fixtures to v2.0.0, I'm getting this error when trying to load my fixtures:

In AbstractFixture.php line 78:
Too few arguments to function Doctrine\Common\DataFixtures\AbstractFixture::getReference(), 1 passed in ... and exactly 2 expected

See my own answer below.

Do you have any question about this error? As doctrine/doctrine-fixtures-bundle doesn't even ship the given class, I would assume you've updated any other package as well?

Solution
At the reported line, add a second parameter to getReference() with the class of the referenced object (i.e. not the Fixtures class), e.g.:
$this->getReference('testuser', User::class);

Background
The change was introduced in https://github.com/doctrine/data-fixtures/pull/464, and released in doctrine/data-fixtures 2.0.0
And doctrine/doctrine-fixtures-bundle 3.7.0 added support for doctrine/data-fixtures 2.0.0.
So if you don't have doctrine/data-fixtures explicitly mentioned in your composer.json, you got it  automatically upgraded to v2.0.0.
So, to prevent surprises like this in the future, add this to your composer.json:
"doctrine/data-fixtures": "^2.0",


There is even a tool to check this kind of issue: https://github.com/maglnet/ComposerRequireChecker
